# Mule: Key of a map contained in a spring bean to be constructed at runtime by concatenating from flowvar and a property in MEL

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

Having a hashmap in a spring bean(detail) whose keys at runtime are to be constructed using a concatenation of flowVars (msVendorCode) and a property read from a property file(QUEUENAME & QUEUEROUTINGKEY)

```
 <amqp:outbound-endpoint exchangeName="${QUEUEEXCHANGE}" queueName="#{detail.vendor['#[flowVars.msVendorCode]' + '${QUEUENAME}']}" connector-ref="vendorConnector" routingKey="#{detail.vendor['#[flowVars.msVendorCode]' + '${QUEUEROUTINGKEY}']}" doc:name="AMQP" />
```

How can i at runtime construct a map key  for a map in a spring bean by concatenating flow variable and a property. The expression used above is setting null to routing key and queuename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
queueName="#[app.registry.detail.vendor[flowVars.msVendorCode] + '${QUEUENAME}']"
```